# Groups order and groups collapsed state is lost after updating row data in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid

I am developing a React/Redux application and using the ag-grid library.

On adding and updating a row of ag-grid data the redux state is updated. Once I am passing this list through a prop to a component, ag-grid is refreshed every time the state change. After ag-grid data refresh the order of groups change and every groups collapse.

Is there a way to keep ag-grid state using its API?

Comment: You might be able to fix it with `rememberGroupStateWhenNewData={true}` as a gridOption. Btw at the moment even rememberGroupStateWhenNewData doesn't work for me.

Comment: Let's see if you have same bug as me, try to add `groupDefaultExpanded={1}` instead and see if it jumps to that default elvel after being updated

Comment: Hi @Pedrammarandi. rememberGroupStateWhenNewData works perfectly. Just have to figure it out how to keep groups order. Thanks. Do you have some plunkr where I can see the problem?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#default-group-order there is a solution to keep the order.